# MGGarlic Data Set in SAS

Tags: sas

I have several SAS tutorials which refer to SASUSER.MGGARLIC. Example code below:

```
proc print data=sasuser.MGGarlic (obs=10);
   title 'Partial Listing of Garlic Data';
run;
```

The above is from below link in github

https://github.com/mariosegal/SAS/blob/master/Stat%20I/st102d02.sas

Likewise, I have quite a list of tutorials, but I am unable to find mggarlic data set. Does anyone have it, can some one please upload to google drive from where I can download. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, requests for software libraries are off-topic here.  Your best bet is to go to the tutorial itself; odds are the tutorial will inform you where to find these datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally someone help me find it on github:

https://github.com/sharmasw/SAS-Public

Thanks everyone